# Regex to find if a string contains two matching substrings

Tags: regex

I have a case where I want to match two substrings in a string.

Example string: `"8080 = 8090, 8080, 8900"`

Basically, the need is to find out if any *comma-separated* substring on the right hand side of "=" is equal to a substring on the left hand side.

I tried reading about Backreferences etc but was unable to find anything similar.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work. BTW your example is not comma separated...

```
^(.+?)=.*\b\1\b.*
```

The idea is about referencing a found group (left side) in the right side.